# Geometric interpretation of Pythagorean_theorem in complex plane?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

The Pythagorean theorem written as
$$
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
$$
has the simply geometric meaning that the sum of the areas of the two squares on the legs ($a$ and $b$) equals the area of the square on the hypotenuse $c$

[image]

But algebraically the Pythagorean theorem can also be written using complex numbers like
$$
(a + ib)(a - ib) = c^2
$$
Here instead of a sum, we have a product of two complex quantities. Can the latter equation also be interpreted geometrically somehow?

Answer (score 10):

Amazingly, you can interpret this.  Notice that we have

$$a+ib=\overline{a-ib}$$

That is, they are conjugates.  Thus,

$$z\overline z=|z|^2$$

Or,

$$(a+ib)(a-ib)=|a+ib|^2$$

The absolute value of a complex number is it's distance from $0$, or, graphically,

[image]

That is,

$$c=|a+bi|$$

Comment: Since $c$ is a real number shouldn't the point z be somehow on the Re axis, too?

Comment: @asmaier No.  $|\cdot|$ always makes things a positive real number, and I assumed $c>0$.

Comment: Would $c=|a-bi|$ be correct, too?

Comment: @asmaier Yes.  If you think about that, that would just be the graph flipped upside down (referring to image in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

maybe worth noting that if $[a,b,r]$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple, with hypotenuse the odd positive integer $r$, and $a$ the other side of odd length, then the Gaussian integer $a \pm ib$ has "exact" square roots:
$$
 \sqrt{a\pm ib} = \pm \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{r+a}2} \pm i\sqrt{\frac{r-a}2} \bigg)
$$
since the quantities in the surds are perfect squares.

conversely, by squaring the Gaussian integer $(m+in)$, with $m \gt n \gt 0$ we obtain $(m^2-n^2)+2imn$, yielding the Pythagorean triad $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$