# Geometric interpretation of the hyperbolic pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hypercomplex-numbers

Multiplying the identity
$$
\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2x = 1
$$
with $c^2$ and defining $a^2= c^2\cosh^2$ and $b^2= c^2\sinh^2$ we get a hyperbolic version of the pythagorean theorem:
$$
a^2-b^2 = c^2
$$
In analogy to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128035/geometric-interpretation-of-pythagorean-theorem-in-complex-plane) I try to find a geometric interpretation by factorizing this relation
$$
(a + jb)(a - jb) = c^2
$$
where I used the imaginary number $j^2 =1$ so I get a product of two [Split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number). What I find confusing is that I could also factorize this relation using real numbers
$$
(a + b)(a - b) = c^2
$$
So there are two ways to factorize the hyperbolic pythagorean theorem.

Now my question is: How does one interpret the hyperbolic pythagorean theorem geometrically? And can one interpret the two ways of factorization also geometrically in two different ways?

Comment: imaginary number $j^2=1$?? For the imaginary unit $i^2=-1$ one has $(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Note that this is not the hyperbolic pythagorean theorem, the correct such version is $\cosh c=\cosh a\cosh b$.

Comment: @PeterMelech OP mentions that $j$ is the imaginary unit in the *split-*complex numbers, not the usual complex numbers.

Comment: @Travis Thanks! Actually I never heard of these numbers. That´s why I was confused!

Comment: @ReneSchipperus As mentioned at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Useful_relations the relation I start from is "similar to the Pythagorean trigonometric identity".

Comment: @PeterMelech They're probably not described much in isolation in part because, (1) while they admit a natural real quadratic form $a + jb \to a^2 - b^2$, this form is indefinite (but still nondegenerate), (2) as an $\Bbb R$-module, the split-complex numbers is isomorphic to the more familiar $\Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R$.

Comment: @Travis Yes, but the connection to the Minkowski plane is definitely interesting. Thanks.